Transformers - ValueError: Asking to pad but the tokenizer does not have a padding token
Im running a RAG pipeline using Haystack (haystack-ai==2.6.0) and HF model & the transformers library (transformers==4.39.3). 
This is how my code looks:
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path=mymodel, cache_dir=cache_dir)
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    # tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': tokenizer.eos_token})
    # tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

embedder = SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder(model=mymodel)
text_embedder = SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder(model=mymodel)
generator = HuggingFaceLocalGenerator(model=mymodel)

rag_pipeline = Pipeline()

rag_pipeline.add_component("converter", MarkdownToDocument())
rag_pipeline.add_component("splitter", DocumentSplitter(split_by="sentence", split_length=2))
rag_pipeline.add_component("embedder", embedder)
rag_pipeline.add_component("text_embedder", text_embedder)
rag_pipeline.add_component("retriever", MilvusEmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store, top_k=3))
rag_pipeline.add_component("writer", DocumentWriter(document_store))
rag_pipeline.add_component("prompt_builder", PromptBuilder(template=prompt_template))
rag_pipeline.add_component("generator", generator)

rag_pipeline.connect("converter.documents", "splitter.documents")
rag_pipeline.connect("splitter.documents", "embedder.documents")
rag_pipeline.connect("embedder", "writer")
rag_pipeline.connect("text_embedder.embedding", "retriever.query_embedding")
rag_pipeline.connect("retriever.documents", "prompt_builder.documents")
rag_pipeline.connect("prompt_builder", "generator")

results = rag_pipeline.run({
    "converter": {"sources": [file_path]},
    "text_embedder": {"text": question},
    "prompt_builder": {"query": question},
})

print("RAG answer:", results["generator"]["replies"][0])

When running the rag_pipeline.run() method, I get the follwing error regarding the tokenizer&embedder:
ValueError: Asking to pad but the tokenizer does not have a padding token. Please select a token to use as `pad_token` `(tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token e.g.)` or add a new pad token via `tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})`.

I saw already some questions and pages regarding a similar issue, but still did not manage to debug the issue in this RAG pipeline (e.g. this stackoverflow question, or this github issue).
Please note that I commented out in the beginning of the code different versions I tried to create the pad token:
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    # tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': tokenizer.eos_token})
    # tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

But they all result in similar error. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
mymodel = "occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5" (https://huggingface.co/occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5)
I'm importing the embedders from haystack not from sentence-transformers:
from haystack.components.embedders import SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder
from haystack.components.embedders import SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder

And also tried with custom wrappers for the embedders to make sure they use the tokenizer, but i still get the same error:
# Custom Wrapper for Document Embedder
class CustomDocumentEmbedder(SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder):
    def __init__(self, model_name, cache_dir=None):
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir=cache_dir)
        # Ensure pad_token is set correctly
        if self.tokenizer.pad_token is None:
            self.tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': self.tokenizer.eos_token})
        super().__init__(model=model_name)

    # Override the embed method to force the tokenizer with padding
    def embed(self, documents):
        inputs = self.tokenizer([doc.content for doc in documents], padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        embeddings = self.model.encode(inputs["input_ids"])
        return embeddings

# Custom Wrapper for Text Embedder
class CustomTextEmbedder(SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder):
    def __init__(self, model_name, cache_dir=None):
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir=cache_dir)
        # Ensure pad_token is set correctly
        if self.tokenizer.pad_token is None:
            self.tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': self.tokenizer.eos_token})
        super().__init__(model=model_name)
        
    # Override the embed method to force the tokenizer with padding
    def embed(self, text):
        inputs = self.tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        embeddings = self.model.encode(inputs["input_ids"])
        return embeddings

# Custom Wrapper for HuggingFace Generator
class CustomGenerator(HuggingFaceLocalGenerator):
    def __init__(self, model_name, cache_dir=None):
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir=cache_dir)
        # Ensure pad_token is set correctly
        if self.tokenizer.pad_token is None:
            self.tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': self.tokenizer.eos_token})
        super().__init__(model=model_name)

    # Override generate method to ensure tokenizer is used correctly
    def generate(self, query, **kwargs):
        inputs = self.tokenizer(query, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        output = self.model.generate(inputs["input_ids"], **kwargs)
        generated_text = self.tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        return generated_text

embedder = CustomDocumentEmbedder(model_name=mymodel)
text_embedder = CustomTextEmbedder(model_name=mymodel)
generator = CustomGenerator(model_name=mymodel)


Please indicate which model you are using.

occiglot-7b-eu5

This is a base model, can generate text but does not follow instructions and is meant to be further fine-tuned. I would try the instruct version, instead: https://huggingface.co/occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5-instruct. LMK if it helps..

not really, but thanks. What I realized is that I have to use a different model for tokenization&embedding. so now I'm using for the generator mymodel = "occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5-instruct" and for the embedding embedding_model = "Alibaba-NLP/gte-Qwen2-7B-instruct". It compiles now, but does not provide proper answers (empty responses from the rag_pipeline for results["generator"]["replies"][0]

opened a new question with the current issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79062223/rag-with-haystack-compiles-but-returns-empty-responses   thanks for the help here
