RAG with Haystack: compiles but returns empty responses
My RAG pipeline (using Haystack) compiles and runs, but is returning empty responses.
From my checks, I thought it might be due to the embedding and llm models not being compatible, so I changed to an embedding model that is based on same as my llm model (both based on mistral).
mymodel = "occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5-instruct"  # llm model
# embedding_model = "Alibaba-NLP/gte-Qwen2-7B-instruct"  # old embedding model
embedding_model = "intfloat/e5-mistral-7b-instruct"

My relevant imports are as follows:
from haystack import Pipeline
from haystack.components.builders import PromptBuilder
from haystack.components.embedders import SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder
from haystack.components.embedders import SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder
from haystack.components.generators import HuggingFaceLocalGenerator

Embedders & generator:
embedder = SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder(model=embedding_model)
text_embedder = SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder(model=embedding_model)
generator = HuggingFaceLocalGenerator(model=mymodel)

indexing pipeline (question is relevant to the uploaded document):
indexing_pipeline = Pipeline()

indexing_pipeline.add_component("converter", MarkdownToDocument())
indexing_pipeline.add_component("splitter", DocumentSplitter(split_by="sentence", split_length=2))
indexing_pipeline.add_component("embedder", embedder)
indexing_pipeline.add_component("writer", DocumentWriter(document_store))

indexing_pipeline.connect("converter.documents", "splitter.documents")
indexing_pipeline.connect("splitter.documents", "embedder.documents")
indexing_pipeline.connect("embedder", "writer")

query_pipeline:
query_pipeline = Pipeline()

query_pipeline.add_component("text_embedder", text_embedder)
query_pipeline.add_component("retriever", MilvusEmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store, top_k=3))
query_pipeline.add_component("prompt_builder", PromptBuilder(template=prompt_template))
query_pipeline.add_component("generator", generator)

query_pipeline.connect("text_embedder.embedding", "retriever.query_embedding")
query_pipeline.connect("retriever.documents", "prompt_builder.documents")
query_pipeline.connect("prompt_builder", "generator") 

.run() calls:
indexing_pipeline.run({
    "converter": {"sources": [file_path]},
})
results = query_pipeline.run({
    "text_embedder": {"text": question},
})
print("RAG answer:", results["generator"]["replies"][0])

The output is simply: RAG answer: 
Additionally, when loading the embedder the following line is shown: Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
Im not sure if the issue is in the models I picked? or in my pipeline (maybe the document and text embedders together cause an issue?)
Im happy to get any advice, help with this.

EDIT 1: Following @Stefano-Fiorucci's suggestions, did the following changes:

separated the pipeline to indexing and query (see the code above).
here is the code for the prompt, maybe the issue is here? :

prompt_template = """Answer the following query based on the provided context. If the context does
                     not include an answer, reply with 'I don't know'.\n
                     Query: {{query}}
                     Documents:
                     {% for doc in documents %}
                        {{ doc.content }}
                     {% endfor %}
                     Answer:
                  """


tested also with Alibaba-NLP/gte-large-en-v1.5

But unfortunately, I still get empty string from the system.
the complete output for results (i.e. query_pipeline.run({"text_embedder": {"text": question},})) is:
{'generator': {'replies': ['\n']}}

As I said in a previous answer, I would separate indexing and query pipelines... Also, I would use a classic embedding model to start. E.g. Alibaba-NLP/gte-large-en-v1.5.

thanks. Did as you suggested (I think?) but still have the same issue.

This generator does not automatically apply the chat template while the corresponding chat generator does. Try applying the chat template to your prompt (https://huggingface.co/occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5-instruct/blob/d13d3d7311bb5b995ded5b065bb583b5ddd8943e/tokenizer_config.json#L46) or use the chat generator. We can also provide support on Discord.
